# EOSIO Account Creation

Tags: eosio.system

I have installed eos by docker method. I am able to create wallet, import wallets etc. But whenever I try to create account, it shows nodeos not running.

I checked `docker ps -a` , it shows dockers are running in the port. and the follwing output is obtained.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
5b924bc39264        eosio/eos-dev       "/bin/bash -c 'keosd…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                   keosd
ccdae6a64975        eosio/eos-dev       "/bin/bash -c 'nodeo…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp   nodeos
```

What can be done to rectify the above problem?

Regards
Swarnalatha

Comment: can you specify the command you used for creating account?

Comment: cleos create account eosio eosio.token EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV is the command which i gave

Comment: Try "cleos get info" . If it returns chain info, then your node is running well. If it still shows 'nodeos not running', then the issue is with your nodeos. 

For performing wallet operations, nodeos is not required. Thats why create wallet and import wallet are working